# How can I twist a curve, but keep the extrusion at a uniform diameter?

Tags: modifiers, surface-deform

I'm trying to take a circle curve, twist it, then extrude it with a uniform diameter throughout. But no matter what I try the twist is also affecting the extrusion. The pictures show what I'm doing in Blender vs the desired result I'm looking for (done in Cinema 4D).

I thought maybe I'd make the main curve shape, twist it, then apply the modifier to bake it in, but that just reverts it to the default circle shape. This is driving me crazy!

[image: What I'm getting in Blender]

[image: Desired result done in C4D]

Comment: Instead of Applying the Modifier, go to Object > Convert > Mesh and then Object > Convert > Curve. Then, Extrude the curve or Bevel

Comment: Ah! That's cumbersome but gave me the desired result, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

..Another cumbersome method to get around the order of events... (The native Bevel takes effect *before* the *Simple Deform > Twist*, implicitly converting to a mesh, which is then deformed.)

This is pretty much @Emir 's comment, bottled as a GN Modifier:

[image]

Thus:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! A Geo Nodes solution I think might actually be preferable to what I was trying